# How to replace(delete) some information from CSV file using python correctly?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, replace

I want to delete some information from the CSV file, but I got some problems.

The following is my CSV file information.

[image]

I used `re.sub` to delete some information, but I will delete the wrong things.

The following code is my example:

`new_html_code = re.sub('" target="_blank">.*</a>', " ", new_html_code)`

I want to delete only the following HTML code:

```
" target="_blank"><img src="https://upload.cc/i1/2020/02/20/g7no03.jpeg" alt="https://upload.cc/i1/2020/02/20/g7no03.jpeg" data-src="https://upload.cc/i1/2020/02/20/g7no03.jpeg" onload="DrawImage(this)" width="300" height="617"></a>
```

However, my code will delete more information. It will delete more information in the following:

```
" target="_blank"><img src="https://upload.cc/i1/2020/02/20/g7no03.jpeg" alt="https://upload.cc/i1/2020/02/20/g7no03.jpeg" data-src="https://upload.cc/i1/2020/02/20/g7no03.jpeg" onload="DrawImage(this)" width="300" height="617"></a><br><br>之前大家落咗名嘅口罩訂購-Waiting List:<br><a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1gu33q5_XO3PqhwRm7rGLQrwNuScfDlvPvCCHRd81Fdk" target="_blank">https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1gu33q5_XO3PqhwRm7rGLQrwNuScfDlvPvCCHRd81Fdk</a><br><br>無收到PM訂口罩都可以訂搓手液, 要填呢張form<br><a href="https://forms.gle/YmQewsz1z689QtKx7" target="_blank">https://forms.gle/YmQewsz1z689QtKx7</a>
```

I have a lot of `</a>` in each field. I know my code is detecting the last `</a>`. I want to make it to detect the first`</a>`, instead of the last `</a>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a ? will solve your problem in a way that makes your regex non greedy. But it will detect all the patterns which in your case, there are 3.

Try something like this: `" target="_blank">.*?</a>`

```
new_html_code = re.sub('" target="_blank">.*</a>', " ", new_html_code)

new_html_code = re.sub('" target="_blank">.*?</a>', " ", new_html_code ,1)
```

Parameter 1 is replacing only first term.

Comment: When I add ```?``` , I can solve my problem. Thank you